# why is time differences using alias not working?

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT
  t.imei,
  t.date,
  t.time startTime,
  t.ignition,
  t.tripStartStop,
  (
    SELECT
      min(time)
    from
      gps_data
    where
      time > t.time
      and date >= t.date
      and imei = '358480088853405'
      and tripStartStop = 0
  ) ' stopTime',
  SUBTIME('startTime', 'stopTime') AS diff
from
  gps_data t
where
  imei = '358480088853405'
  and date >= '2020-03-08'
  and date <= '2020-03-09'
  and tripStartStop = 1
```

the above query returns startTime and stopTime as alias values but i can't get the difference of these two times

used both SUBTIME and TIMEDIFF

Comment: Share the output ERROR?

Comment: no errors are showing just displaying '00:00:00'

Comment: Although it's decidedly odd to subtract the bigger thing from the smaller thing

Comment: tried both ways bigger from smaller and smaller from bigger

Comment: You could try wrap everything except the subtime-line in a subquery and seelct from startTime, stopTime and ` SUBTIME('startTime', 'stopTime') AS diff` from it.

Comment: Aliases are not available in the select you need to repeat the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select 'starTime' and 'stopTime' using select statement within the Substring. That would solve your problem.

SUBTIME(SELECT(startTime),SELECT(stopTime))

`````
SELECT t.imei
     , t.date 
     , t.time startTime
     , t.ignition
     , t.tripStartStop
     , ( SELECT min(time) from gps_data where time>t.time and date>=t.date and imei='358480088853405' and tripStartStop=0 ) ' stopTime'
     , SUBTIME(SELECT(startTime),SELECT(stopTime)) diff 
  from gps_data t 
 where imei='358480088853405' 
   and date>='2020-03-08' 
   and date<='2020-03-09' 
   and tripStartStop=1````
`````

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use aliases like that. The query:

```
SUBTIME('startTime','stopTime')
```

treats the `startTime` and `stopTime` as strings, hence the `00:00:00`.

What you can do is following:

```
select q.imei, q.date, q.startTime, q.ignition, 
       q.tripStartStop, q.stopTime, subtime(q.startTime, q.stopTime)
from (
  SELECT t.imei
       , t.date 
       , t.time startTime
       , t.ignition
       , t.tripStartStop
       , ( SELECT min(time) from gps_data where time>t.time and date>=t.date and imei='358480088853405' and tripStartStop=0 ) 'stopTime'
  from gps_data t 
  where 
    imei='358480088853405' 
     and date between '2020-03-08' and '2020-03-09' 
     and tripStartStop=1
) as q
```